# Unable to run actuator/busrefresh end point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-bus

I get this error while I try to send post request to  .................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................**http://localhost:8888/actuator/bus-refresh** :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1663260534141,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/actuator/bus-refresh"
}
```

Server Dependencies :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Client Dependencies :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springbus.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_bus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring_bus_client</name>
    <description>spring_bus_client</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Client Application Properties

```
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888

management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

Server application Properties

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=/home/jj/Spring_Bus/configrepo

server.port=8888

spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
#spring.cloud.config.profiles=native

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they moved the endpoint to `busrefresh` at some point, have you tried that? Need to change it here `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` and make the right `POST` request (should be empty, unless you want to explicitly specify the destination).

Also make sure to follow their [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/reference/html/) about setting this whole thing up. I would also check that the topic used for the messages is set up (default is `springCloudBus`).